# HLLAPI Search Presentation Space (Function 6)

Tags: function, websphere, ibm-midrange, hllapi

have someone an Exemple for the HLLAPI Function „Search Presentation Space“?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]